# How can I append a note to the current currently clocked in task

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I would like to quickly append a note to the currently clocked in task - something like a capture. I don't believe there is anything out of the box to do this, but it seems it must be possible.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capture template can have a target of `clock`, which will file to the entry being clocked.  Here's an example template that stores a note in a plain list item.

```
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
             '("C" "to clocked" item
               (clock)
             "- %?"))
```

Comment: Currently the note gets logged into a drawer because org-log-into-drawer is true, which is what I want for everything except this. Is there anyway to make it not log into the drawer?

Comment: You can set the `LOG_INTO_DRAWER` property on a subtree to overrule `org-log-into-drawer`